# ZABBIX 6, i cant write a querying an internet resource using zabbix. I need to receive 200

Tags: linux, zabbix

I'm polling internet resources using zabbix. I need to receive 200 response codes during the day. If 200 code is not received, then I get "problem" as a trigger. Can I somehow calculate the number of problems per day? That is, I need to get the percentage of resource availability for 24 hours.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUsWq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylymE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhN7V.png)

Maybe it should be done through the data element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [service monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/it_services):

> Service monitoring is a business-level monitoring that can be used to
> get an overview of the entire IT infrastructure service tree, identify
> weak places of the infrastructure, calculate SLA of various IT
> services, and check out other information at a higher level. Service
> monitoring focuses on the overall availability of a service instead of
> low-level details

You can configure service level according to the problem triggers, define trees of dependant services etc.

You can create service actions as well, to react to SLA changes